# Duplicate names in Plot

Tags: r, duplicates

I have dataset that contain a column called cuisine
In the cuisine table, each record can contain values like "Indian, Italian" and so on
Now i have:

```
  pizza  132
  pizza,  257
```

I want the highest among them to appear on the plot, so i want "Pizza," to appear not both of them

My Code:

```
  cuisine <- Corpus(VectorSource(dataSet$Cuisines))
  dtm <- TermDocumentMatrix(cuisine)
  m <- as.matrix(dtm)
  v <- sort(rowSums(m),decreasing=TRUE)
  d <- data.frame(word = names(v),freq=v)
  head(d, 100)
  d <- subset(d, freq>=100)
  # use aggregate to create new data frame with the maxima
  df.agg <- aggregate(freq ~ word, d, max)
  # then simply merge with the original
  df.max <- merge(df.agg, d)
  df.max

  df.max %>%
    mutate(name = fct_reorder(word, freq)) %>%
    ggplot( aes(x=word, y=freq)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity") + labs(title= "Cuisines") +
    coord_flip()
```

Data:

```
     word freq
1     american,  332
2         asian  108
3        asian,  127
4        bakery  310
5       bakery,  435
6     beverages  172
7       biryani  105
8        burger  107
9       burger,  144
10         cafe  364
11        cafe,  343
12      chinese 1506
13     chinese, 1229
14  continental  254
```

The problem is that it makes duplicated names like i explained above to appear, how can i fix this issue.

Comment: Please share a small reproducible sample of data to illustrate the problem and test solutions. Something like `dput(droplevels(df.agg[1:10, ]))`

Comment: The problem is that you need to clean your text before performing any kind of count; you don't have "duplicate words" you have some that still have punctuation... Look at the example in `?TermDocumentMatrix `